# How to parse a log file .evtx to get a collection of unique strings for output

Tags: powershell

I try to get log file .evtx using command:

```
Get-WinEvent
```

In the output, I get a lot of text, an example:

```
An account was logged off.

Subject:
    Security ID:        MYDOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME1-MD$
    Account Name:       COMPUTERNAME1-MD$
    Account Domain:     MYDOMAIN
    Logon ID:       0xKK228
```

How can I output only unique strings with the value

```
Account Name: *ANYCHAR* - MD$
```

How do I parse all the strings, given that all the characters before

```
-MD$
```

can be different? And after parsing, convert it to a list of unique values and write it to a file?

Comment: Try this, there is no need to parse: `$log = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{LogName = 'Security'; ID = 4634} -MaxEvents 1` __=>__ `$log.Properties[0]`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Hello! Thank you for answer. Can I completely output the log with only the computer names so that the entries are not repeated? I need this to collect statistics on the number of computers that have logged into the domain over the past two days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred method would be using `Get-WinEvent` in combination with an [`EventLogPropertySelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventing.reader.eventlogpropertyselector):

```
# Create an event property selector to grab the user name value
$selector = [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPropertySelector]::new([string[]]@('Event/EventData/Data[@Name="TargetUserName"]'))

# Call `GetPropertyValues` on each event, pass the selector as the only argument,
# then pipe to Group-Object
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{Path='.\path\to\log.evtx';Id=4634} |ForEach-Object GetPropertyValues $selector |Group-Object -NoElement
```

Output will be a list of distinct usernames and a count of how many occurrences were found

---

The snippet above makes use of PowerShell 5.0's constructor syntax. For this to work in PowerShell 3.0 or 4.0, change the first statement to:

```
$selector = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPropertySelector @(,[string[]]('Event/EventData/Data[@Name="TargetUserName"]'))
```

Comment: Thank you! Please, help me: i try ro run script on windows server 2012r2 and get error: "Method invocation failed because [System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventLogPropertySelector] does not contain a method named 'new'."

Comment: thank you very much! Please, tell me, how do I modify the $selector variable so that I can output results by the name TargetUserName, but only if it contains the string "- nb" or "- ds"? is it possible? For example: 1. Account Name: COMPUTERNAME1-DS$ | 2.  Account Name: COMPUTERNAME2-DS$ | 3.  Account Name: COMPUTERNAME3-DS$ and etc. I need to output how many times computers whose names contain "- nb" or "- ds" log on or log off (it doesn't matter) in security log

Comment: Filter the output from `Group-Object` with `... |Where-Object { $_.Name -match '-(NB|DS)'}`

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the xml of an event...

```
Get-WinEvent security  -MaxEvents 1 | % { [xml]$xml = $_.toxml(); $xml }

Event
-----
Event
```